# How do I pass array keys to an array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I'm very new to PHP and I'm stuck on the basics. I'm not sure how to use arrays in PHP.

I have the following code:

```
$districts['BG'] = array_keys($states_districts);       

return $districts;
```

From this I get a lot of array items, for example "District 01, District 02, District 03 - ...99". This is creating a dropdown menu for districts in WooCommerce and I need the options to have assigned values, same as their names. So I need to format my array in the following manner:

```
$districts['BG'] = array(
  'District 01' => 'District 01',
  'District 02' => 'District 02',
  'District 03' => 'District 03',
  'District 04' => 'District 04'
);
```

Much appreciated! I'm still new to programming even, but I'm guessing a foreach loop is needed?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Might I ask why do you feel you need to duplicate this data? How are you using it? Is there a specific reason you couldn't just use the value in two different places?

Comment: If it's necessary and not under your control (if some functionality of WooCommerce expects an array in this format), have a look at [`array_combine`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine).

Comment: This is simple... just foreach the array then make each value...key and value of new array...

Comment: Because I'm editing the WooCommerce states and I think that WC needs values to work properly. There are two places where the states are used, in the dashboard and on Checkout. The states are already in the dropdown menu, but currently it's not working. I've tried adding values and it worked.

Comment: Thank you, El_Vanja, that indeed does! Such a simple solution, thank you!